# Cruisecontrol.net run on .net 4

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have inherited a project that uses CruiseControl.net and I am trying to get it running on Win Server 2012; CruiseControl.NET needs .NET 3.5.  I'm running into an (apparently) well known problem  that .NET 3.5 doesn't come enabled on a standard Win Server 2012 install.

I've followed instructions to use an alternate source by downloading the Win Server 2012 installation ISO and mounting it but it still doesn't work.  I suspect that something on my virtual server is causing me a problem and my hosting company is being typically unhelpful!

So I'm wondering if CruiseControl.NET and it's asssociated applications (CCTray) can be told to run on .NET 4?  If so how can I do that?

Thanks, in advance, for any and all help!

Regards,

Neil

Answer (score 0):

you can download the 1.8 bracnh source, and recompile in .NEt 4.0
or use master branch, which is set to 4.5